# how to bind a datagrid with a class contains object of another class

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

sry but i`m new with wpf, 
i have a class called generatedMessage and am trying to bind it with a datagrid.

```
class generatedMessage
{
    public CanMessage cmsg { set; get; }
    public int cycleTime { set; get; }
    public generatedMessage(){}
}
public class CanMessage
{
    public byte[] data { set; get; }
    public ushort dlc { set; get; }
    public ushort flags { set; get; }
    public uint id { set; get; }
    public ulong res1 { set; get; }
    public ulong res2 { set; get; }
}
```

as u see generatedMessage class have an object of CanMessage class, i have done this before with the CanMessage class like below

```
TraceTable.Items.Add /*- at TraceTable is a datagrid -*/
(
   new CanMessage()
   {
       data = msg.data,
       dlc = msg.dlc,
       id = msg.id,
       flags = msg.flags,
       res1 = msg.res1,
       res2 = msg.res2
   }
);
//xml file below
 <DataGrid x:Name="TraceTable" Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow" Margin="0,45,4,0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=data}"  Header="Data" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=dlc}" Header="DLC" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=id}"  Header="ID" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=flag}" Header="Flag" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=res1}"  Header="Res1" IsReadOnly="true"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=res2}" Header="Res2" IsReadOnly="true"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

**so my question is how to make it with generatedMessage class ? i want the datagrid to view all canMessage attributes + cycle time (a datagrid with 7 columns)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand question properly, then you should add items of type "generatedMessage" and do binding like:

```
Binding={Binding cycleTime}
Binding={Binding cmsg.dlc}
...
etc.
```

Generally you shouldn't add items manually to DataGrid. The best way to do it: create ObservableCollection in a ViewModel and set attribute "ItemsSource" in DataGrid:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
```

then add items to this collection, not to DataGrid.
To better understood that topic you could read about MVVM pattern ;-).